# How to specify version of BerkeleyDB when creating file using perl DB_File?

Tags: php, perl, berkeley-db

We seem to have hit a version incompatibility in BerkeleyDB between our perl scripts and our PHP scripts.  Our perl scripts generate BDB and our php scripts merely read them.

Our perl scripts use DB_File to create a BDB file:

```
use DB_File;
$DBFILE="output.db";
tie(%db, "DB_File", $DBFILE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644)
    or warning("Could not open db file '$DBFILE'");
```

This previously created a file of type:

```
$ file output.db
output.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)
```

But, after an upgrade of sys-libs/db and DB_File, now creates a file of type:

```
$ file output.db
output.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 10, native byte-order)
```

At the other of the system we have a PHP script.  When the upgrade occurred, our PHP code (based on dba_open()) started complaining about the version:

```
Notice:  dba_open(): output.db: unsupported hash version: 10 in dbread.php on line 16
```

I have tried upgrading PHP, but version 10 doesn't seem to be supported yet.

Is there a way to tell perl's DB_File to create a specific version when creating the DB?

Comment: How big is the file?  Could you generated "right" Berkeley DB version from text input on the target system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to tell perl's DB_File to create a specific version , AFAIK libdb itself doesn't have that feature

If you compile/link against version 4.x of libdb, then DB_File only gets to use that version

So if you need DB_File that uses libdb-4.x you will have to downgrad or install another copy in a different @INC directory

When installing this is the file you edit  https://metacpan.org/source/PMQS/DB_File-1.835/config.in

Simply change `DBNAME = -ldb-2.4.10` to match the version that your php install used

Specify a different install directory with https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#INSTALL_BASE then tell perl where to find it with https://metacpan.org/pod/perlrun#PERL5LIB

https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib also documents this